# how to write laravel show method route url in jquery

Tags: laravel

i have created a link using HTML

```
 <a style="text-decoration: none; " href="{{URL::route('category.show', $category->id) }}">{{$category->name}}</a>
```

instead of using the normal link, i want to use jQuery to achieve this

```
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $category->name; ?>" onClick="getPage(<?php echo $category->id; ?>);" /><?php ?>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function getPage(id) {
  $('#output').html('<img src="LoaderIcon.gif" />');

  jQuery.ajax({
           url: "{{ URL::route('category.show', $category->id) }}",
           // i don't know how to declare the route URL in jQuery.

           data:'id='+id,
           type: "POST",
           success:function(data){
                           $('#output').html(data);
                                 }
             });
       }
getPage(1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your URL path as below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">var BASEURL = "'.$this->baseUrl.'";  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getPage(id) {
      $('#output').html('<img src="LoaderIcon.gif" />');     
      var path=BASEURL+'/category/'+id;  // define path here
      jQuery.ajax({
          url: path,            
          data : {id: id},
          type: "POST",
          success:function(data){$('#output').html(data);}
      });
 }
getPage(1);
</script>
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: its not working, its only getting the image but not getting the content of the view i want to display after clicking